# Doctrine and MongoDb: Define required fields in MongoDb-Document (

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine, doctrine-mongodb

I'm using MongoDB with Doctrine for a Symfony project.

For a document (I call it `class Product`) I need to define a field (e.g. name), but I want to act doctrine in a way that the document cannot be saved without defining a it. Meaning, whenever creating or updating a new Product, the property `$name` has to be defined.

For doctrine and MySql this is quite simple. There you have to say:

```
class Product {

   ...

   /** @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=false) */
   private $name;

   ...

}
```

Is there a **similar way in MongoDb**?

The following code (which I found in a similar thread) doesn't work:

```
class Product {

   ...

   /**
    * @MongoDB\Field(type="string")
    * @Constraints\NotBlank
    */
   protected $name;

   ...

}
```